# Image slider not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am building a page where I am fetching images in a loop for each form name.Now suppose there are four forms,so there will be four slider consecutively one below the other.Now the problem I am facing is that when I am fetching the first slider images are only visible others are not,others are blank.I thing because the slider are not unique because the slider div id are same for all within the while loop.Can any one guide me how to solve this...and make each slider unique.

```
<div id="now_slider">
    <?php 
        include( "connect.php"); 
        $a=mysql_query( "Select * from bang where active=1"); 
        $i=0; 
        while($res=mysql_fetch_array($a)) { 
          $name=$res[ "t"]; 
          $pdf=$res[ "pt"]; 
          $id=$res[ "f"]; 
    ?>
        <h1><?php echo $name; ?><span></span></h1>
        <br />
        <!-- DC Flick Slider Start -->
        <div style="width: 100%; margin:0 auto; padding: 0px 0; position:relative;">
            <!-- navigation controls-->

            <div class="navig-photo-stack ps">
                <a class="prev"></a>
                <a class="next"></a>
            </div>
            <section id="slide">
                <div id="ps-slider" class="ps-slider">
                    <!-- Slide 1 -->
                    <div id="ps-albums">
                        <?php $b=mysql_query( "Select * from fim where f='$id'"); while($res1=mysql_fetch_array($b)) { $img=$res1[ "im"]; ?>
                        <div class="ps-album" style="opacity:0;">
                            <img src="forms/<?php echo $img; ?>" />
                            <div class="ps-desc">
                                <!--<div class="ps-head">
                                      <h3></h3>
                                    </div>-->
                                <!--<div class="ps-cont"> <span> </span> </div>-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- /section slide -->
        </div>
        <?php if($pdf!="" ) { ?>
            <h2><center>To Download the Form Click Below<br /><a href="./forms/<?php echo $pdf;?>" download="form"><img src="images/pdf.png" alt="" width=80 height=80 /></a></center></h2>
        <?php } ?>
        <!-- DC Flick Slider End -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Post code atleast for one form! And FYI Slider div IDs must be **unique**!

Comment: you can post the code with the question.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak how can I make slider unique,i cannot do it with id as it is already defined